# TypeError with multilevel inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, maya, multi-level

I have 4 different classes:

```
meta
  -> Limb
      -> Arm
      -> Leg
```

meta is the base for every class. Limb inherits from meta. Arm and Leg inherit from Limb

The Arm.py and Leg.py files have exactly the same code, just some different strings for naming conventions.

When I do the following:

```
import Limb.Arm
reload(Limb.Arm)

import Limb.Leg
reload(Limb.Leg) 


def build():
    arm = Limb.Arm.Arm()

build()
```

I get the error:

```
# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Limb instance as first argument (got Arm instance instead) #
```

However, when I try to build the Leg module...

```
import Limb.Arm
reload(Limb.Arm)

import Limb.Leg
reload(Limb.Leg) 


def build():
    leg= Limb.Leg.Leg()

build()
```

Everything works just fine:

```
==> SUCCESS: L_Leg created!
```

If I comment out loading the Leg module like this, the code also runs just fine for the arm.

```
import Limb.Arm
reload(Limb.Arm)

#import Limb.Leg
#reload(Limb.Leg)
```

Can someone explain why this happens? Does something get overwritten when importing the Leg module after the Arm module has been imported, because they both inherit from the Limb module? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create a namespace and then it should work

```
import Limb.Arm as limbArm
reload(limbArm)

import Limb.Leg as limbLeg
reload(limbLeg) 


def build():
    arm = limbArm.Arm()
    leg = limbLeg.Leg()

build()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in the same error. I got it working by making 2 different functions for building the arm and the leg, and just importing the Arm and Leg modules in those functions and not at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I came up with this. I don't know if this is "correct" way of doing it, but something it works:

```
def build_leg():
    import Limb.Leg
    reload(Limb.Leg)

    leg = Limb.Leg.Leg() 

def build_arm():
    import Limb.Arm
    reload(Limb.Arm)

    arm = Limb.Arm.Arm()


build_leg()
build_arm()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to know without seeing how you have you module laid out. But this sounds like you've inverted the layout of the classes so that `Limb` is getting redefined by your imports. You probably want to organize your package like this:

```
 limb
   + core.py 
   + arm.py
   + leg.py
```

with the common base class in `core.py`.  In `arm.py` and `limb.py` you'd import `core.Limb` and inherit from it.  That will allow you to iterate on the derived classes without messing up the inheritance at reload time.